# How to make an enumerable<block> without a foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using EF6 and I was wondering is there anyway to chain extensionmethods to get an IEnumerable< Block> (the block that is used in FlowDocument) without a foreach. The code below returns IEnumerable< Aye>.

```
    public IEnumerable<Block> GetInitialAyes()
    {
        return Context.Set<Aye>().Where(c => c.SooreId.Name == "x").ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this general form:

```
public IEnumerable<Block> GetInitialAyes()
{
    return Context.Set<Aye>().Where(c => c.SooreId.Name == "x")
        .Select(aye => /* Convert Aye to Block here */ )
        .AsEnumerable();
}
```

or alternatively, depending on the complexity of the `Select()` logic, for Linq to Entities it may be necessary to use `ToList()` to force the execution of the query:

```
public IEnumerable<Block> GetInitialAyes()
{
    return Context.Set<Aye>().Where(c => c.SooreId.Name == "x")
        .ToList()
        .Select(aye => /* Convert Aye to Block here */ );
}
```

Comment: return Context.Set<Aye>().Where(c => c.SooreId.Name == "الفاتحة")
                .Select(a => new Paragraph(new Run(a.Context))).ToList();

Comment: @TheDeparted Sorry I forgot `Select()` would return an `IQueryable` here.  I updated the answer to show using `AsEnumerable()` which would be better for performance reasons.

Comment: ok ty but there is a new problem that EF says "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities" and basicly i cant do:Paragraph(new Run(a.Context)) and i also cant do: new Paragraph(){Inlines = new Run(a.Context) } becuz inline property is readonly.

Comment: i guess i have to write it into varriable then turn it into IEnumerable< Block>

Comment: @TheDeparted The `ToList()` might work better for you then because it will execute the query on the database and you can use standard LINQ  `Select()` which should support parameters in constructor.  The `AsEnumerable` is generally more efficient, but I believe `ToList()` / `Select()` performance is no worse than `ToList` / `foreach`

Comment: Does this work:

    return Context.Set<Aye>().Where(c => c.SooreId.Name == "x")
        .ToList()
        .Select(aye => new Paragraph(new Run(a.Context)));

Comment: yes it did work ty. i generally like to use extension methods than for each and in some cases i see that filtering works better when ef does it rather than when its done by C# on memory.